# Python Image Library ellipse with wide outline

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

When creating an ellipse with PIL, is it possible to have a thicker/wider outline? Currently, I'm trying to do `canvas.ellipse(box, outline=colour, fill=None)`, but would like to be able to give the `outline` parameter a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [aggdraw](http://effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm) advanced-graphics add-on module to PIL -- with it, the method to draw an ellipse, like others, takes a `pen` object which you can make with your favorite width (as well as color and opacity).

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!