# Outline width in Python

Tags: python, draw, outline

I'm painting a ellipse with Python like this:

```
draw.ellipse((20, 180, 180, 20), fill = 'blue', outline ='blue')
```

I want the edge is thicker, but I do not know what property or value would have to modify / add.

Comment: Using PIL? If so indicate that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Image Library ellipse with wide outline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517778/python-image-library-ellipse-with-wide-outline)

Comment: Yes, I am using PIL:

`from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import aggdraw`